# How do you divide gain for the first and second stages of the two stage opamp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

For this two stage opamp, how would you divide the gain for the first and second stage? 
For example the target gain is 2000 V/V, then you would have many option to divide the gain like  **45/45**, **30/70**, **70/30**, etc.
So how do you dertermine gain for the first and second stage?

Because many people asked for more detail so I'll give a specs as an example.
[image]
**EDIT:**
I'm talking about open loop DC gain and this is for integrated circuit design.
If someone is confused, [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.5142132) is a design example. 
The page 2/5 has a specs table with open loop gain.
https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.5142132

[image]

Comment: 45/45 seems odd numbers. They add to 90.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm taking about V/V so 45*45 = 2000.

Comment: Interesting question, and, just to seed the discussion, I am not an expert, but @LvW, Hearth, and Andy aka are... Would that be related to; operating point, operating margins, GBW, inherent offset (and might be more)?

Comment: Depends on a bunch of things, I wouldn't expect one single answer. For example, there may be some maximum gain you can achieve on the output stage when driving some specified low impedance. Then the input stage has to make up the rest.

Comment: Why 5 M’s instead of 6 or 8? You haven’t given any I/O specs for impedance voltage or load? You don’t even have self bias for DC either. Why not?

Comment: But as far as gain goes , it all in 2nd stage, but without NFB, it is DC unstable

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That is the very basic two stage amplifier. These ideal current source should be implemented by pmos and a current biasing with mirror. The current sources are what you have to design. No one gives that in advance. You have to reply on the power consumption to set the current. 
It seems that people here are not familiar with ic design so I'll add more specs just in case it is needed.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 this is just the opamp alone so NFB is not related here. You're designing the opamp not using it in a circuit. You can compensate to have a good phase margin using the basic Miller compensation technique.

Comment: The input impedance of your config, is very low with NFB on M5 thus loading the gain of 1st stage,  which is why I said all your gain is in the 2nd stage

Comment: If you know how to design IC’s why such a poor configuration  instead of a better one like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2cG1.jpg

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the one above is supposed to drive capaictive load only. It's the basic structure for people to learn about design.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the one you sent is just a folded cascode with nmos and pmos input to extend the ICMR and a buffer at the output to drive resistive load. It is just one choice.

Comment: It’s not just a choice but a commerical OA with exceptionally high BW, where are your specs?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I editted the post with the specs above. I did not try to make the best opamp or comerical one. I'm trying to design a basic two stage opamp above and wonder how to divide the gain for each stage. I understand that there are many better opamp topologies out there but all of that depends on you application. Some application you don't need a very high dc gain or high bandwidth, you just make one just enough but low power.

Comment: Yes but unless you define the impedance and power specs, choosing gain parameters affects the parameters for CC , bias, power , gm and Ron. Suchas adding oh BTW this is for high current capacitive loads

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  there is a capacitive load CL, power consumption in the specs. I don't try to design a specific one in mind, just trying to design  general one. You can set the specs. The folded cascode you sent is actually easier to design as it's just one stage (without buffer) and no need for compensation. The two stage opmap is more difficult to design and compensate and more things to learn. 
Bias current is what you should choose from the power consumption specs. It's what a designer should do. Similar for Ron, Gm. If you already fix them then what else to do?

Comment: Define your source & output impedance and load resistance for each stage in order to compute gain?  Using excess gain for 2nd stage NFB to reduce Zo

Answer (score 4):

I would design the input stage for functionality which would result in an input stage transconductance (I/V) of whatever it turned out to be and then compensate the amplifier by selecting the size of the compensation capacitor to get adequate phase margin. The size of the compensation capacitor, Cc would normally set the transimpedance (V/I) of the second stage.

So the gain of the first stage would be just whatever it turned out to be after being designed (reduced by input pair emitter degeneration) and then set the gain of the second stage by choosing the compensation capacitor value to give adequate phase margin.

The open loop gain is the transconductance of the first stage multiplied by the transimpedance of the second stage and this is multiplied by the feedback fraction to give the loop gain and the compensation capacitor is chosen to make the loop phase a fair bit less than 360 degrees when the loop gain is unity.

**EDIT**

I think you're looking at things from the wrong perspective. The last amplifier I designed (a power amplifier), I didn't even consider what the dc gain was to be, I've never actually measured the dc gain of that amplifier and so even now I have no idea of its actual value. It's far more important to consider what happening at the high frequency end, the selection of the compensation capacitor to ensure that there is adequate phase margin. A designer would usually be more concerned with the high frequency end when designing an amplifier. So I definitely wouldn't proceed by deciding on a dc gain and then trying to divide it between the two stages in any particular fashion. I would design the three stages to try to create an amplifier with low distortion and the dc gain of each stage would be whatever it turned out to be. The important thing then would be to compensate the amplifier to guarantee closed loop stability. What's happening at the low frequency end is pretty immaterial.

Having said all that, when designing a precision op amp, the dc gain is required to be very high but even then I would expect a designer to probably try to maximise the dc gain of each stage rather than deciding on an overall open loop gain and then trying to decide how to divide it up between the two stages.

In a bjt amplifier the gain of the first stage is proportional to the tail current in the differential amplifier and reduces with increasing input pair emitter degeneration. In the second stage the dc gain is proportional to beta and to Rc.

Comment: The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per answer, any further comments posted here to discuss the answer, might be deleted without notice. So...  **Keep it in chat, please!** Any updates to the answer which are decided during the chat, can be made via an edit to the answer, as usual. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128109/discussion-on-answer-by-james-how-do-you-divide-gain-for-the-first-and-second-st).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Looking at all the information you provided, I interpret your question more along the lines of "what is the optimal approach to allocate gain to each stage in a 2 stage miller compensated op amp?" The main constraint you give is overall gain, which in the example you give is 2,000.

I created three different networks to show an empirical (simulated) result of breaking up the 2 stage gain, using 3 different allocations. Each network can be realized using the 2 stage (differential) pmos input, (common source) nmos output architecture you shared and the results should be comparable. The comparisons will also track. Each stage uses typical miller capacitive feedback compensation in the second to first stage. And the zero resistor compensation is set at 1/gm output stage, as is common. The parasitic capacitances were set asymmetrically to give a better comparison, which doesn't depend on the parasitics being exactly sized.

The thing to notice about each design is that there is a tradeoff between bandwidth (ft = GBW = unity gain bandwidth here) and phase margin.

Larger gain in the first stage (ex. A) will push the bandwidth out further but tradeoff with less phase margin then the other cases. Smaller gain in front (ex. B) gives less bandwidth but better phase margin. Using the geometric mean of gain for each stage (ex. C) gives somewhere inbetween. The point being that there isn't a general optimal allocating function that you would minimize or maximize. This should also be apparent as the relationship between fT and PM is not convex.

Mathematically, this makes sense as the \$f_T\$ is just $$gm_{in}/Cc$$ Higher gain in the first stage input results in greater bandwidth (fT).
PM (Phase Margin) can be shown to be approximately $$180 - \tan^{-1}(GBW/p1) - \tan^{-1}(GBW/p2)$$  If you swap the pole positions, which will occur by swapping stage gains, either way, the system with the higher GBW will consume more phase margin, as expected from the simulations.

You might use larger gain in the first stage with larger transistor devices for lower noise, or you might adjust the open loop output impedance depending on your intended load resistance. I don't know of any literature describing this specific question, but most of the literature uses the larger gain in front, likely for noise, matching, etc. Your design really depends on your overall intended constraints and priorities.

Comment: nice try!
One thing is the parasitic caps are fixed. However, they depens on the transistors' sizing. 
Would that affect much to the phase margin and stability, bandwidth of the opamp?

Comment: The beauty of using the simpler models I built, is that they emulate the sizing pretty well. I built one of these using the 2 stage opamp you showed, and examples were very close. The simple parastic caps are just an approximation of the total capacitance at each node. You can adjust to emulate or build with more specific FET models.

Comment: In your third circuit `v2c`, two stages have the same gain but the parasitic caps are different. Also how about if you add load capacitance, `CLoad = 10pF`? How would you size the miller capacitance?

Comment: Same capacitances won't change the relationship I described much at all. (v2c). Large load capacitance will reduce bandwidth (and less obvious pm). I'd recommend to build the models in ltspice and play with them (no fet models required here - simple L1). And a good classic book to refer to is Allen and Holberg "CMOS analog design"

Comment: I have all these books, Razavi, Allen, Holberg books.  People normally choose Cc > 0.22 CL to get a good phase margin.

Comment: this is not a complete answer but i'll reward the bounty as it's the only one answer the asked question.

Answer (score -2):

This configuration has many drawbacks and almost not any advantages at all.Some of the drawbacks:

1)low gain
2)gain is a function of Vin+ and Vin-
3)(VCC+)-(VEE-) must be relatively small

The only advantage it has Vo can be from VCC+ to VEE-

I suggest you use this configuration instead (made of BJTs instead of MOSFETs)

[image]

Operation and Advantages and Disadvantages are on the image as well.