# Stepping down 5.3/12 V DC to 4.8 V

Tags: dc, constant-voltage

I have load that requires a constant DC voltage of \$4.85 V \pm 10 mV\$ and can draw up to \$3A\$.

I have tried to power my load with a \$12V\$ power-supply regulated with a LM350T (+ heat sink), however, I can't dissipate the heat generated by the regulator. My other power-supply provides a voltage of \$5.3 V \pm 200 mV\$, but I don't know which circuit could convert this source voltage to the load requirement.

How can I solve this problem without getting a new power-supply?

**Edit**

I have not stated my requirement properly. What I need is an average input voltage of \$4.85 V \pm 10 mV\$ with the actual range of \$\approx [ 4.5 ; 5 ] V \$. The load is a \$64 \times 64\$ LED-Matrix powered by \$3.3 V\$ data signal from an ESP32. The whole circuit draws around \$2.2 A\$ when all LEDs are fully powered.

I can dissipate around \$2 W\$.

**Edit**

The specification of matrix can be found by searching for *joyit elv 64x64 matrix* (or directly https://files2.elv.com/public/25/2511/251186/Internet/251186_data.pdf and https://files2.elv.com/public/25/2511/251186/Internet/251186_um_eng.pdf).

The datasheet is very vague and basically states:

- Supply voltage \$5 V\$
- Max power consumption \$40 W\$
- Protocol HUB75E (\$\frac{1}{32}\$ scan)

I'm using this library to drive it with a NodeMCU ESP32-WROOM-32: https://github.com/mrfaptastic/ESP32-HUB75-MatrixPanel-DMA

My pin assignment:

| Name | Pin | Name | Pin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | G25 | R2 | G14 |
| G1 | G26 | G2 | G12 |
| B1 | G27 | B2 | G13 |
| A | G23 | B | G22 |
| C | G5 | D | G17 |
| E | G32 | LAT | G4 |
| OE | G15 | CLK | G16 |

**Possible Reason**

Thanks to the comments I have observed the following:

1. When I supply \$4.85 V\$ to both the matrix and the MCU everything works.
2. When I power the MCU from a different source (e.g. USB \$5 V\$) the matrix allows a supply range of \$\approx [3.85; 4.85] V\$ before dimming evenly.

**For everyone with the same problem**

So I assume that because I have \$3.3 V\$ logic level and not \$5 V\$ the matrix needs less input voltage. But when I provide less than \$4.85 V\$ the voltage regulator on the MCU cannot provide \$3.3 V\$ for the ESP32. I have always assumed the matrix was the problem.

Comment: How much heat can you dissipate?

Comment: You'll need a switching power supply (not linear). Try Texas Instruments' Webench Power Designer online tool. Put in your requirements and it will spit out multiple solution options. Also consider if you really need 10mV accuracy - that's an extremely tight spec, especially over a wide current draw range.

Comment: What kind of load does have requirements like that?

Comment: Regulators have output impedance, so it is not usually possible to make a very low noise power supply for a load that draws variable current. However +/-10mV should be okay. But you need to explain what the load is and what the current looks like, especially how it varies, because the regulator transient response and output impedance will be a major part of the error budget.

Comment: @td127 you can do this with a linear regulator, though you'd need a very low dropout one, which most likely means some control loop idiosyncrasies.

Comment: Please make title and body of your post agree on input supply. The WEBENCH® designs seem neither carved out for low ripple, nor fully specified for total noise. Too bad including a, say, PI filter in the feedback loop gives rise to stability concerns. In your specification, try to specify *accuracy* and "each" aspect of *stability* (mV/°, %ripple, mV/h, mV/A, …) separately. Consider buck to about 6.4 V & linear to 4.85 V.

Comment: (4S NiMH, if ±10 mV was noise rather than accuracy.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers and for the WEBENCH® tip. I have updated the post. I'm fairly new to electronics so I will try my best to fully understand your response @greybeard.

Comment: Why would you need regulated voltage for LEDs?

Comment: More and more pixels stop working if I supply less or more than 4.85 V.

Comment: Can you put a schematic of the matrix?

Comment: An LED matrix(-module - MAX7221/7219?) shouldn't be that picky - please provide (a pointer to) specifications.

Comment: @terrakuh If it only works at 4.85 V then there is probably something else wrong. Are all the wires for the power connections of sufficient size and connected properly? Is there anything you can add to "pixels stop working" - such as some of them flicker or are at reduced brightness? Have you tried adding a capacitor of maybe 10 μF very close to the MCU across its power pins?

Comment: I have added 330 Ohms resistors on each data line near the input of the matrix to protect against the over- and undershoots I was getting (maybe completely unnecessary with 3.3 V LL for 5 V?). The data lines are about 20 cm longs and all cable sizes should be more than enough. I have tried also a cheap LM2596 circuit board with 12 V input and it seems to working apart from a row at one end.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping! I have learned a lot and found a promising reason. I will have to redesign the circuit a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LDO to regulate 4.85 V from 5.3 V. 2 Amps with 20 mV variation corresponds to 10 mΩ supply impedance.

Either look for an integrated LDO with appropriate specs or:

- Pick a P-MOSFET that can dissipate up to 1 W continuously
- Regulate its gate voltage based on output feedback. This can either be done [with a single PNP transistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/583712/237061), or more mundanely, with an opamp.
- If you specify up to which frequency you need such low impedance, one could suggest more specific solutions.